# List is not generated in trigger

Tags: trigger, list

While I insert data through data loader and check this debug.Debug log generates only one value for clientIds.So, I am getting only value for objList though I am inserting multiple records for custom object and clientIds is a list(no set).

Thanks for your help!

```
for(custom_objcet__c obj:trigger.new){
        clientIds = clientMap.get(obj.custom_objcet__c);
        if(clientIds==null){
            clientIds = new list<Id>();
        }
        clientIds.add(obj.Client__c);
        clientMap.put(obj.custom_objcet__c,clientIds);                  
}   
system.debug('print clientIds'+clientIds);  
custom_objcet__c[] objList=[Select custom_objcet__c,Client__c 
                            From custom_objcet__c 
                            Where Client__c IN:clientIds];
```

Comment: I assume that because you are calling `clientIds = new list<Id>();` within a loop its the reason you are only seeing 1 item in it.

Comment: @BarCotter I want the map of clientMap as string and list of ids.Can i get that.Also the clientIds as a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are do everything you are doing as we do not know where you are using it elsewhere so give this a shot:

```
for(custom_objcet__c obj:trigger.new){

        if(!clientMap.containsKey(obj.custom_objcet__c))
            clientMap.put(obj.custom_objcet__c,New List<Id>{obj.Client__c});
        else
            clientMap.get(obj.custom_objcet__c).add(obj.Client__c);


        clientIds.add(obj.Client__c);

}   
system.debug('print clientIds'+clientIds);  
custom_objcet__c[] objList=[Select custom_objcet__c,Client__c 
                            From custom_objcet__c 
                            Where Client__c IN:clientIds];
```